# When I type git init in Command Prompt, it says "Permission Denied"

Tags: mysql, git, heroku

I'm trying to upload a fullstack website on heroku app and I was following a tutorial on it. After I logged into Heroku i typed git init to remote connect onto my heroku repository but after typing it, it gave me this error message

```
C:\Users>git init
C:/Users/.git: Permission denied
```

I don't know why it does this? can anyone help me?

Comment: You don't seem to have permission to make a repo there. Why are you putting it there?

Answer (score 0):

The [Deploying with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) Heroku documentation suggest to use `git init` inside a local folder representing your project.

```sh
cd myapp
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .git/
git add .
git commit -m "My first commit"
```

Then:

```sh
heroku create
Creating app... done, ⬢ thawing-inlet-61413
https://thawing-inlet-61413.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/thawing-inlet-61413.git
```

Initializing a Git repository directly in `C:\Users` instead of a local folder representing your project/application is not correct.
You should use it inside the folder representing your fullstack website.